# wchar to char in c++

Tags: c++, string, unicode, windows-ce

I have a Windows CE console application that's entry point looks like this

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

I want to check the contents of `argv[1]` for `"-s"` convert `argv[2]` into an integer.  I am having trouble narrowing the arguments or accessing them to test.

I initially tried the following with little success

```
if (argv[1] == L"-s")
```

I also tried using the `narrow` function of `wostringstream` on each character but this crashed the application.

Can anyone shed some light?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be:

```
if (_tcscmp(argv[1], _T("-s")) == 0)
```

Comment: i think `wcscmp` is preffered

Comment: I changed it to `_tcscmp`, which is the most flexible.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (argv[1] == L"-s")
```

This is not correct even for narrow strings as you compare pointers. You need

```
if(wcscmp(argv[1],L"-s")==0)
```

or

```
if(std::wstring(argv[1])==L"-s")
```

Answer (score 0):

`argv` is an array of `char*`, not `string`, so the usual comparison with == won't work.  That if-statement is comparing two pointers.  Can you construct a `wstring` and then compare?

```
if (wstring(argv[1]) == L"-s")
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to convert the argv[] entry to a string and then do the comparison.
[link text][1]

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/81778/Converting-TCHAR-to-string-while-getting-PC-Name.aspx

[1]:

The above link would help if you can do a conversion to string.